# unable to execute js from the java code of a android phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova

i've written a plugin for android which when called from the js of my app, calls a particular js function of my app with a parameter.
So in the java code for my plugin, its like

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
super.loadUrl("alert('voila');");
```

but this js (alert) is not neing executed. i get an error saying

```
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol.
```

after  it times out. The rest of the app works fine. What could be wrong so that its timing out and not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JavaScript statement is not a url. It needs to be prefixed with javascript: like :

```
super.loadUrl("javascript:alert('voila');");
```

Comment: is there any other way to execute js in a android code, apart from this ?

Comment: There are several other ways. See the web apps section on the Android developer site at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html. Or even easier, use PhoneGap. There are several getting started tutorials for PhoneGap, like http://phonegap.com/start#android or ours at http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start